# Pandas ignores separator passed as parameter

Tags: python, pandas, csv, separator

I am working on a function that among other tasks, is supposed to read a csv in pandas. As one of the parameters, I would like to pass the separator as a string. However, for some reason, probably something to do with regular expressions, pandas is totally ignoring my passed parser and defaults to '\t', which does not parse my data correcty.

```
import pandas as pd

def open_df(separator):
  df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', sep=separator)
  return df
```

Question is, how am I suppose to pass the separator parameter in this case?

Comment: Which seperator are you handing over?

Comment: Works fine for me.

Comment: @LucaG I am giving '\t' or '|', but I have to make it work for any character if possible

Answer (score 3):

Please Check this link:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

> sep : str, default ‘,’
>
> ```
> Delimiter to use. If sep is None, the C engine cannot automatically detect the separator, but the Python parsing engine can,
> ```
>
> meaning the latter will be used and automatically detect the separator
>   by Python’s builtin sniffer tool, csv.Sniffer. In addition, separators
>   longer than 1 character and different from '\s+' will be interpreted
>   as regular expressions and will also force the use of the Python
>   parsing engine. Note that regex delimiters are prone to ignoring
>   quoted data. Regex example: '\r\t'.

Answer (score 1):

I passed the seperator string as "raw" string and that worked fine for me.
I you use a raw string \ is interpreted as a normal character and also \t will work

When you call `open_df()` you have to write a r before the string quotes like `open_df(r"\t")`

Example:

```
test_string = r"\t\n"
print(test_string)
\t\n
```

And I also passed "python" as engine parameter in order to not display the parser warning :-).